# Zend db (postgres) - avoid sql injection

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, zend-db

In MySQL, we may use myql_escape_string. By using Zend DB adapter, what is the equiavalent function for Postgres db?

for example:

```
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO "TableA" 
          (name, address) VALUES (?,?)';

    $statement = $db->createStatement($sql);
    $statement ->prepare();
    $statement ->execute(array($val1 , $val2));
```

What is the function providing from Zend to escape string from the input value? Or I should use PHP like:

```
$statement ->execute(array(pg_escape_string($val1) , pg_escape_string($val2));
```

to each input value?

Comment: You don't need to escape anything if you use prepared statements -- that's the whole point (Zend DB adapter will use prepared statements under the hood).

Comment: You mean pg_query_params() ? Check the manual: http://php.net/pg_query_params